# React Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element on page render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to load my second React component into my HTML page but I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
```

I've attempted other solutions, but I haven't been successful. I started with create-react-app and I did everything the same way as the first component since that's loading up correctly but the second one isn't.

**Root file:**

[image]

**SRC file:**

[image]

**My LiteInfo.js file:**

```
import React from 'react';

const LiteInfo = function() {
  return (
    <div className="LiteInfo">
      <h1>Hello</h1>;
    </div>
  );
}

export default LiteInfo;
```

and I'm trying to load it in the same way as App.js in **index.js** file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import LiteInfo from './LiteInfo';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
console.log(document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(<LiteInfo />, document.getElementById('liteInfo'));
console.log(LiteInfo);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Using console.log shows info, but the error is coming from `ReactDOM.render(<LiteInfo />, document.getElementById('liteIndo'));`

And lastly, my **HTML** file which is found in public):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">

  <title>React App</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="navbar"></div>
  <div id="liteInfo"></div>
  <div id="root">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

[image]
[image]

Comment: `liteIndo` => `liteInfo`?

Comment: @mur7ay change `document.getElementById('liteIndo'));` to `document.getElementById('liteInfo'));`

Comment: I corrected it to liteInfo but it's still showing the same error.

Comment: where in your HTML are you loading your script?

Comment: That's the entire script. I figured since it was working without one with what came with create-react-app it wasn't necessary.

Comment: entire HTML page**

Comment: My guess would be a typo somewhere. [Your code works fine](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dnckkd)